# How do I sort an array of 12 people into a smaller array of 4 families?

Tags: java, arrays

How do I take an array which contains 12 people and their incomes from an infile and sort it into a smaller array of 4 families and their total incomes? This is what I have so far.

```
public class Assignment7Sasha
{
  public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
  {
   String lname[] = new String[12];
   String fname[] = new String[12];
   double income[] = new int[12];
   int deductions;
   int i;
   double taxrate;
   double familytax;
   double familyincome;
   double adjustedfamilyincome;
   PrintWriter outfile = null;  
  outfile = new PrintWriter
          (new FileOutputStream("Prog7Results"));//Results are the last names sorted into 4 different families 
    Scanner infile=new Scanner(new FileInputStream("Prog7FamilyInfo.dat"));
 for( i=0;i<12; i++)
  {
   lname[i] = infile.next();
   fname[i] = infile.next();
   income[i] = infile.nextInt();
 }
 for(i=0; i<12; i++)
     outfile.println(lname[i] + "\t"+ fname[i] + "\t"+income[i]);
    //object is created and the constructor is invoked
    Assignment7Sorting nm = new (lname, income, outfile);

nm.sort();
 outfile.println("The sorted list of families and their adjusted incomes is:");
    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
      outfile.println(lname[i]+ " " + adjustedfamilyincome[i] + " " + familytax[i]);
    infile.close();
    outfile.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want the new array to contain?

Comment: Java is an Object-Oriented language. Use it. Create a class to store the values of a `Person`. To answer your question: *"How do I take an array which contains 12 people?"* You start by only have **one** array, not three. That way you can sort it.

Comment: Sorry, but your question doesn't make sense.  You cannot "sort" 12 things into 4 things.  You can maybe "sort" 12 things into 4 **piles** of things, but that is a different meaning of the word "sort" to what we use in IT.  (The correct word for that operation is "collating".)  To make progress on this, you need to 1) reread the requirements, 2) make sure that you really understand the requirements and 3) explain them to us in clear IT English ... not colloquial English that fails to convey the true meaning.  (Yes.  Clear communication is very important in IT.)

Comment: I suspect that if you do steps 1) and 2) you will find that step 3) is unnecessary; i.e. that you will gain a deeper understanding of what you are supposed to be doing, and you will be able to make progress without our help.

Comment: @SaurabhShirodkar Some of the people in the list have the same last name. Using the infile (which is the list of 12 people and their incomes) I need to print to an outfile each family and their total income (each line is a family last name and that families income). I hope that elaborates on my initial question.

Comment: Do look up documentation and practice using multiple classes and their interactions with each other. That will help you in the long run!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is pretty vague, so I will attempt to answer it based on what information you are giving.

You can create a static class to hold the income, last name and other attributes of each family that you may want. You can use an ArrayList to maintain a dynamic list of such objects, and go through the list using an Iterator object.

```
public class Assignment7Sasha{
    private static final class Family{
        String lname;
        int income;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        //All variable declarations
        ArrayList families = new ArrayList<Family>();

        //Read into arrays lname, fname and income as you have done

        for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
            boolean exists = false;
            Iterator it = families.iterator();
            while(it.hasNext()){     //Check if lname[i] already exists in families
                Family f = (Family)it.next();
                if(f.lname.equals(lname[i])){   //If lname[i] already exists
                    f.income += income[i];
                    exists = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!exists){     //If lname[i] doesn't exist
                Family f = new Family();
                f.lname = lname[i];
                f.income = income[i];
                families.add(f);
            }
        }

        Iterator it = families.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            Family f = (Family)it.next();
            //Handle each Family object however you want
            System.out.println("Family:" + f.lname + " Income:" + f.income);
        }
    }
```